# Why is [[eosio::on_notify("eosio.token::transfer")]] not working?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code, eosio.cdt

[image]

[image]

Network: kylin testnet.

I transferred eos to this contract, but it the "deposit" function was not called. What do I miss?

Comment: CDT version: v1.6.1

Comment: Trying to help here: Can you specify the part "not working". Can you please edit the question 1) what is the result you are expecting to happen 2) what actually happens?

Comment: sorry, I added that result.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the action wrapper is needed to map the transfer action to the deposit function, the notification by itself is not sufficient.

try adding to ln15 of header:

```
[[eosio::on_notify("eosio.token::transfer")]]
void deposit(name from, name to,asset quantity, string memo);
```

```
using transfer_action = action_wrapper<name("transfer"), &hello::deposit>;
```

Comment: Please explain your answer with a few lines. StackExchange guidelines encourages us to set posts into a context, so that others can understand your solution more easily.

Comment: updated, the answer to include more lines on context. I believe the action wrapper is needed to map the transfer action to the deposit function, the notification by itself is not sufficient.

Comment: where is the official documentation for how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **EOSIO_DISPATCH** with **ACTION** keyword,
then replace **ACTION** keyword with **[[eosio::action]] void** from your .hpp file and remove **EOSIO_DISPATCH** from your .cpp file of smart contract.

As **EOSIO_DISPATCH** blocks **eosio::on_notify**.

Also check: **[[eosio::on_notify("VALID_EOSIO_ACCOUNT_NAME::VALID_EOSIO_ACTION_NAME")]]** Ref: https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosio.cdt/v1.6/guides/generator-attributes

Please closely check eosio.token contract you will get how use.
https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/tree/master/contracts/eosio.token