# How to debug eosio::on_notify("eosio.token::transfer") actions?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.token, transfer

I'm working on a contract that will run an action when receiving tokens. The following code does **not** run when the account receives EOS or JUNGLE tokens on the Jungle Testnet.

```
#include "./test.hpp"

...

void test::init(name username)
{
    require_auth(_self);
}

void test::ontransfer(name from, name to, asset quantity, string memo)
{
    check(true == false, "sorry not sorry");
}
```

```
#include <string>

#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosio/asset.hpp>

#define EOS_SYMBOL symbol("EOS", 4)

CONTRACT test : public eosio::contract
{
    using contract::contract;

  public:
    struct init
    {
        init(){};
        eosio::name name;
        EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(init, (name))
    };

    ACTION init(eosio::name username);

    [[eosio::on_notify("eosio.token::transfer")]]
    void ontransfer(eosio::name from, eosio::name to, eosio::asset quantity, std::string memo);

     // https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/4381/why-is-eosioon-notifyeosio-tokentransfer-not-working 
    using transfer_action = eosio::action_wrapper<eosio::name("transfer"), &test::ontransfer>;

};

EOSIO_DISPATCH(test, (init))
```

How can I debug this? Is this a problem of v1.6.1? Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Does this code work on the main net?

Comment: I have not tested in mainnet yet, that would be useful. I reverted back to the old way of doing it, by defining the apply function. It would be useful as to why this code doesn't work on at least jungle.

Comment: With CDT 1.6.1, the `on_notify` attribute does not work when you explicitly use `EOSIO_DISPATCH`, so try to remove the dispatcher as it is no longer mandatory with CDT 1.6.

Answer (score 7):

Using the `EOSIO_DISPATCH` macros disables the automatic inclusion of actions and `on_notifys`, and assumes that you will deal with them manually.

To fix this, you have to remove the `EOSIO_DISPATCH` macro from your header file.

An additional note, as of eosio.cdt 1.6 there is a bug when using `on_notify` with a wildcard for the contract name, this can be fixed with a hack where a `on_notify` is added with a given contract name. For example:

Replace:

```
[[eosio::on_notify("*::transfer")]] void ontransfer(eosio::name from, eosio::name to, eosio::asset quantity, std::string memo);
```

with:

```
[[eosio::on_notify("*::transfer")]] void ontransfer(eosio::name from, eosio::name to, eosio::asset quantity, std::string memo);
[[eosio::on_notify("eosio.token::transfer")]] void dummytansfer(eosio::name from, eosio::name to, eosio::asset quantity, std::string memo){ontransfer(from,to,quantity,memo);} // This is a hack, otherwise the ontransfer function won't work
```